# React tabbed content based on dynamic data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to build out some tabbed content [based on this tutorial](https://alligator.io/react/tabs-component/). When I set up my app exactly like the tutorial, everything works great. The problem is I want to build these tabs with dynamic content, and sometimes there will not be any content for one or more of the tabs, so I am attempting to generate the tabs based on the data coming in.

Here is what I have attempted:

```
let tab1 = "Tab 1";
let tab2 = "Tab 2";
let tab3 = false;
let tab4 = "Tab 4";

class Gallery extends Component {
  render() {
    let tabs;

    if (tab1) {
      tabs += (
        <div label="Gator">
          See ya later, <em>Alligator</em>!
        </div>
      );
    }
    if (tab2) {
      tabs += (
        <div label="Croc">
          After 'while, <em>Crocodile</em>!
        </div>
      );
    }
    if (tab3) {
      tabs += (
        <div label="Sarcosuchus">
          Nothing to see here, this tab is <em>extinct</em>!
        </div>
      );
    }
    if (tab4) {
      tabs += (
        <div label="Gator">
          See ya later, <em>Alligator</em>!
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      // THIS WORKS
      <Tabs>
        <div label="Gator">
          See ya later, <em>Alligator</em>!
        </div>
        <div label="Croc">
          After 'while, <em>Crocodile</em>!
        </div>
        <div label="Sarcosuchus">
          Nothing to see here, this tab is <em>extinct</em>!
        </div>
      </Tabs>

      // THIS DOESN'T
      // <Tabs>
      //   {tabs}
      // </Tabs>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Gallery />, rootElement);
```

If you comment out the hardcoded child divs within the Tabs component and uncomment the one where I am using the `tabs` variable, you can see that there is an error. The error is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined` on `line 15` of `Tabs/index.js` so it would appear that the children aren't being rendered before the `activeTab` state is being set. Maybe I am going about this all wrong anyway. Is there a better way to dynamically populate these tabs?

## [CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-lovelace-irq8k)

**Note that in my actual implementation, the tab1/2/3 is actually JSON, I just hardcoded them as variables for this question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting your children to be an "array" therefore just concatenating JSX won't do.

> You need to create an array with those JSX elements and pass in as children

```
class Gallery extends Component {
  render() {
    let tabs = [];

    if (tab1) {
      tabs.push(
        <div label="Gator">
          See ya later, <em>Alligator</em>!
        </div>
      );
    }
    if (tab2) {
      tabs.push(
        <div label="Croc">
          After 'while, <em>Crocodile</em>!
        </div>
      );
    }
    if (tab3) {
      tabs.push(
        <div label="Sarcosuchus">
          Nothing to see here, this tab is <em>extinct</em>!
        </div>
      );
    }
    if (tab4) {
      tabs.push(
        <div label="Gator">
          See ya later, <em>Alligator</em>!
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      // THIS WORKS
      // <Tabs>
      //   <div label="Gator">
      //     See ya later, <em>Alligator</em>!
      //   </div>
      //   <div label="Croc">
      //     After 'while, <em>Crocodile</em>!
      //   </div>
      //   <div label="Sarcosuchus">
      //     Nothing to see here, this tab is <em>extinct</em>!
      //   </div>
      // </Tabs>

      // THIS DOESN'T
      <Tabs>{tabs}</Tabs>
    );
  }
}
```

Working sandbox --> https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-sky-hezzy

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if this helped you. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work